# Python script could not find a filename

Tags: python-2.7

The following simple script could not find the filename 'We are one' that I have in a current directory. What am I missing here?

Thanks much in advance.

```
import re
import os

limit_type = re.compile('We are one|foo\.txt')

#Output should have 1 file named "We are one"
output = os.system("ls -1")

output = str(output).split()

for line in output:
    if limit_type.search(line, re.M|re.I):
        print "Found it %s" % range_type
        exit(0)

print "Not Found it!"
```

Comment: 1. What are you actually trying do do? 2. Why are you using `os.system` to call `ls` rather than using e.g. `os.walk` or `glob`? 3. Have you tried looking at what's *actually in `output`* as part of your debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Use r'' to specify a regular expression, not simply ''
- os.system returns the exit value of the program. In your case, this was 0 rather than the program output. Use subprocess.Popen if you need the output.
- split() splits by spaces, so you would have had a list where you had 'we', 'are' and 'one', but not the phrase 'we are one'. Use split('\n') to split by newlines
- in your print you used variable range_type which doesn't exist.

The following should work

```
import re
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

limit_type = re.compile(r'We are one|foo\.txt')

# Run ls -1 and store stdout output
output = Popen(["ls", "-1"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
output = str(output).split('\n')
print output

for line in output:
    if limit_type.search(line):
        print "Found it: %s" % line
        exit(0)

print "Not Found it!"
```

Comment: I ran your script; it didn't find it; thought the file "We are one" is there. If I replace if limit_type.search(line) with:   if re.search(r'We are one|foo\.txt', line, re.M|re.I):; then it finds it OK.

How can I format a pattern using re.compile, so it would find it?

Answer (score 0):

Change your regex to `re.compile(r'We are (:?(:?one)|(:?foo))\.txt')`.

The `:?` after opening parenthesis means the group is non capturing.

As mentioned by jonrsharpe, it is preferable to use the `glob` module instead of passing `ls` to `os.system`. But you are free to do what you want.

Comment: Got the following errors:
----------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "uexample.py", line 4, in <module>
    limit_type = re.compile(r'We are (?one|foo)\.txt')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 190, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 242, in _compile
    raise error, v # invalid expression
sre_constants.error: unexpected end of pattern